# working of for loop in python 3 having increment problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having a doubt that like other programming languages we can increment in for loop as we want (eg in c  for(i=0; i<5;i+5))  but if we want to do his in python we cant ??????

Comment: `range` can get a step. Also, your loop would run indefinitely because you wrote `i+5`, not `i=i+5` nor `i+=5`.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To write a java for loop in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52906665/to-write-a-java-for-loop-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most "pythonic" way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do it this way:
`for i in range(0,5,5):`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify strides to do what you want:

```
for i in range(0, 5, 5):
    print(i)
```